# IIS Authorization Rules breaks WP REST-API and results in fail in Site Health

Tags: rest-api, iis, authorization

apperently it seems the wordpress rest-api cannot work with restricted authorizations.

when i change the default `Allow All Users` / this:

[image]

to a restricting ad group and remove the `All Users` (obviously):

[image]

which creates this `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" roles="DOMAIN\Test-Group" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

all seems fine

> at first glance,

but if we go to WP Site Health it reveals this errors:

[image]

so it seems the wp REST-Api cannot operate without `anonymous` / `All Users` access.

How can i fix this or am i missing something and need to adjust some settings?

thank you

Comment: The REST API needs to be publicly accessible. Authorization and permission checks are happening inside the application (WP) and should not be done on the server side, as you don't know there if an operation should be available to everyone or a restricted user group.

Comment: thank you for the comment, but what if i am forced to prevent public access? this is a intranet website but not for all members. as i understand the wp docs the REST API is required by WP for various reasons like the block editor etc or other things that could break plugins. the main question is, can i use wp with restricted authorization? if REST API is required the answer would be no :(

Comment: Okay, I see. So access to the whole system is regulated and now Site Health Status is complaining? Personally, I would do a quick check if what you need is still working and then not care about the message. Remember WP caters for a very diverse audience and tools like this are not 100% correct for each individual use case.

Comment: that would be a workaround. Sure it would and can work, but as mentioned, the REST API seems to be already used in WP Core and will certainly be used in future releases. also any future update of anything else like a plugin might break the website if the internal functions implement the REST API :(

Comment: I think this is a false positive. Can you install & update plugins from the wp-admin? Can you use the block editor? If so, you can use the site.

Comment: thank you for your comments, it seems there is no other errors, despite the 2 errors in the site health page. 1. `REST API 401.2 - Unauthorized`  and 2. the `basic login popup` caused by the second error `Your site could not complete a loopback request`. i will have to further check the website after i implemented every other plugin and modification i need and see if errors related to this `authorization` issue are happening